# API Controller in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i'm working on this application, and i wanted some advice on hierarchy of the apis, i have a class User, and a class Student that extends from User, and 3 other classes(StudentCode, StudentConduite and StudentPark) the 3 extend from the Student, the idea is that when the admin trys to add a new Student a new user will be aseked to be added as well (the primary key is in the user class), i thought of checking if the user already  exist in the StudentService class and calling the method that saves the user if he don't already exist, or i check if the user exist in the level of API.

```
//calling the method on StudentService:
@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
     StudentDao studentDao;
     UserDao userDao;
     UserService userService;

    public Student registerNewStudent(Student student) {
        User existingUser = userDao.findById(student.getUserName()).orElse(null);
        if (existingUser ==null) {
        userService.registerNewUser(student);
        }
        return studentDao.save(student);
    }
}


//or i check if the user exist in the api like this :

public class StudentController {
    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;
    private UserDao userDao;
    private UserController userController;
    
    @PostMapping({"/registerNewStudent"})
    public Student registerNewStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
        User existingUser = userDao.findById(student.getUserName()).orElse(null);

        if (existingUser ==null) {

          
            userController.registerNewUser(student);
        }
        return studentService.registerNewStudent(student);
    }
    

}



//and this is registerNewUser methode from Userservice:

  public User registerNewUser(User user) {
        Role role = roleDao.findById("User").get();
        Set<Role> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
        userRoles.add(role);
        user.setRole(userRoles);
        user.setUserPassword(getEncodedPassword(user.getUserPassword()));

        return userDao.save(user);
    }



//and this is registerNewUser methode from UserController:

 @PostMapping({"/registerNewUser"})


    public User registerNewUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.registerNewUser(user);
    }
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should go to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) oriented Stack Exchange site.

Comment: No question asked.

Comment: @fahed, could you answer my comment below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers should not contain any business logic, they only delegate to an appropriate service class which encapsulates all the logic. So, define a service class and place inside it all your logic, calling it from your controller.